# in python what does this do? x = function(arguments)(variable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I've seen some programs in which the below format is used.

```
x = function(arguments)(variable)
```

I've searched on internet but didn't know what it is called and hence couldn't find anything related to this.
I want to know what is this format called, and how does it work.

Comment: It's not a *format*. Functions are first-class objects in Python, so a function call can return *another* function. In your example, the call `function(arguments)` returns a function. Let's suppose the function it returns is `math.sqrt()`.  The the code computes `math.sqrt(variable)` and assigns the result to `x`.

Comment: This isn't anything in particular. We can presume that `function(arguments)` returns some *callable object*, likely another function (or maybe a class), which is *then called immediately*, `function(arguments)(variable)` -> `some_callable(variable)`

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember in python is that everything is an object, even functions. That means that functions can be assigned to variable names and can even be returned from other functions. That is what is being done in your code. Since there are actually two functions being called, let's rename them to `foo` and `bar`. Your function call is then:

```
x = foo(arguments)(variable)
```

The function definition of `foo` looks similar to

```
def foo(arguments):
    def bar(variable):
        return (something with arguments and variable)
    return bar
```

So the function foo returns the *function* bar, which when called returns the result.

This is useful for example in creating decorators.

Comment: The `bar` function doesnt need to be defined inside `foo` does it?

Comment: @MuhdMairaj no. The important thing to understand here is that functions don't behave different than anything else.